# RESTORE database with different name Fails - "The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing"

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have database backup A.bak
I want to restore that backup file, using the SQL Server Management Studio, into database B which has all the same tables/columns but just different name.
If I try to do the restore - I am getting error:

> The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing

How can I resolve this? I tried renaming the `.bak` file but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the "Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)" option:

[image: WITH RELPACE option]

Comment: Thanks Dan. I checked this option and I even installed the database with the same name but again I  am getting the same error when trying to restore the database even with the same name. Do you know how this can be resolved? Thank you in advance

Comment: Personally, I use T-SQL RESTORE. You could try scripting the command to a new query window. Verify the `REPLACE` option is in included and execute it.